# mac autocomplete for ssh hosts in terminal

Tags: macos, ssh

I had used Ubuntu for a while and I have configured ssh aliases for hosts I need to connect through ssh. A few days ago I started using mac book and I moved all ssh info (keys, config) onto my mac. But when I'm typing `ssh project_` and press TAB it does not show possible hostnames, and even when I'm typing `ssh project_sta` and TAB, autocompletion not working.  But when I'm typing the full name like `ssh project_staging` it works, so I assume that everything is okay with the config file

I tried to use the original mac terminal and iterm2, same issue on both. Also, I asked other guys who work on mac, and ssh autocompletion works for them.

My ssh config:

```
Host project_staging
        HostName xxxxx
        User xxxx
        Port xxxx

Host project_production
        HostName xxxx
        User xxxxx
        Port xxxx
```

In real life, I have much more hosts and it's hard to remember all of them.

Any ideas, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

okay, I solve it by adding zsh with oh_my_zsh and add ssh as a plugin to a .zshrc file

Comment: this comment implies a recommendation to use oh_my_zsh which I find very useful. Thank you!

Comment: I liked oh_my_zsh

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me: add this completer in your .bashrc

https://gist.github.com/aliang/1024466

```
_complete_ssh_hosts ()
{
        COMPREPLY=()
        cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
        comp_ssh_hosts=`
            awk '{split($1,aliases,","); if (aliases[1] !~ /^\[/) print aliases[1]}' ~/.ssh/known_hosts ;
            awk '/^Host/ && $2 !~ /[*]/ {print $2}' ~/.ssh/config ;
            `
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${comp_ssh_hosts}" -- $cur))
        return 0
}
complete -F _complete_ssh_hosts ssh
```